# Windows redirect outgoing traffic

Tags: windows, networking, redirection

I need to redirect the network traffic in a Windows server which is destined from the 111.111.111.111:100 address to the 222.222.222.222:100
address, for example.

This would be easy with iptables but cannot find any method on how to do this in Windows.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iptables for Windows to redirect traffic](http://serverfault.com/questions/567058/iptables-for-windows-to-redirect-traffic)

Comment: this is not duplicate because in other question you redirect traffic destined to localhost. In my question i need to rewrite outgoing connection from localhost

Comment: Hey John, did you manage to find a solution? Or did you have to work around that issue?

Answer (score 1):

There's in no built-in way in Windows to route traffic by ports (maybe on server with RRAS, but not that I remember).

You can use a local instance of proxy as [suggested on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11067970/routing-traffic-from-a-specific-application).

Comment: I tried suggested program but i see only 2 option direct and block. In direct i dont see any settings to directing different port.